# In webpack, with an HTML Entry, how do place the content of external script tags into script tags

Tags: html, webpack

Essentially I want to make this: 
`<script src=foo.js />` 
into this: 
`<script> Contents of foo.js </script>` 
for  all scripts in an html file.

Comment: Possibly, I'll look into it. From my initial reading, I think it's very similar but a bit different.

Comment: I agree, it's a duplicate, though the answers are not necessarily helpful for me here.